# Android is writing to Bluetooth GATT twice

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uart

I have an LM-G900UM Android 13 phone and am working with a a chip supporting Microchip's UART LE profile.

The Android device is the host and the chip is the client. It works great, except when it reconnects. When it reconnects, it typically writes the same characteristic twice each time writeCharacteristic is called. After a few seconds, it goes back to writing only once.

Why would it be writing twice?

Here is how the characteristic is written to:

```
                val writeCode = mGatt.writeCharacteristic(rxChar, data, chunk.writeType) // writeType is WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT
                when (writeCode) {
                    BluetoothStatusCodes.ERROR_PROFILE_SERVICE_NOT_BOUND ->
                        mLogger.log(Level.WARNING, "UART service not bound")
                    BluetoothStatusCodes.ERROR_GATT_WRITE_NOT_ALLOWED ->
                        mLogger.log(Level.WARNING, "The receiver RX characteristic is not currently writable")
                    BluetoothStatusCodes.ERROR_GATT_WRITE_REQUEST_BUSY ->
                        mLogger.log(Level.WARNING, "The receiver gatt interface is too busy to write to the receiver")
                    4 -> { // ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_CONNECTED
                        mLogger.log(Level.WARNING, "The receiver is disconnected and cannot be written to. Reconnecting to gatt")
                        connectGatt()
                    }
                    else ->
                        if (writeCode != BluetoothStatusCodes.SUCCESS)
                            mLogger.log(Level.WARNING, "Unknown error writing to the receiver: $writeCode")
                }
                didWrite = writeCode == BluetoothStatusCodes.SUCCESS
```

I have verified, if didWrite is set, the same value is not written again.

Below that, here is how the characteristic write is handled:

```
    override fun onCharacteristicWrite(gatt: BluetoothGatt, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic, status: Int) {
        onCharacteristicWrite(characteristic, status)
    }

    fun onCharacteristicWrite(characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic, status: Int) {
        val data = characteristic.value
        // If this timeout occurs, the data is re-written (this is not appearing in the logs)
        stopWriteTimeout()
        // mWritingChunk is set to a class containing the data just before it is written
        if (mWritingChunk != null) {
            val chunk = mWritingChunk!!
            mWritingChunk = null
            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                mLogger.log(Level.WARNING, "Unable to write to the receiver; Re-adding the write request. The status was: $status")
                writeBuffer.remove(chunk)
                writeBuffer.addFirst(chunk)
            } else if (characteristic.writeType == BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE || Arrays.equals(chunk.data, data)) {
                // This portion is purely for logging
                if (data == null) {
                    if (chunk.data.size > sentenceStart.size + sentenceEnd.size && isASCIIPrintable(chunk.data, 1, chunk.data.size - 2))
                        mLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Did write chunk: " + prettifyLine(String(chunk.data, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)))
                    else
                        mLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Did write chunk: <binary> (bytes: " + chunk.data.size + ")")
                } else if (data.size > sentenceStart.size + sentenceEnd.size && isASCIIPrintable(data, 1, data.size - 2))
                    mLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Did write: " + prettifyLine(String(data, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)))
                else
                    mLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Did write: <binary> (bytes: " + data.size + ")")
                mLock?.didWrite(chunk)
            } else if (data != null) {
                if (data.size > sentenceStart.size + sentenceEnd.size && isASCIIPrintable(data, 1, data.size - 2))
                    mLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Unrecognized write: " + prettifyLine(String(data, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)))
                else
                    mLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Unrecognized write: <binary> (bytes: " + data.size + ")")
            } else
                mLogger.log(Level.WARNING, "Characteristic data was null")
        } else
            mLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Characteristic was written to without flushing any chunk!")
        // Takes the next entry in the buffer to write
        writeFlush()
    }
```

From what is logged, it appears the app is only writing once, but the chip is reporting to write twice.

Comment: Instead of using the default writeType (WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT), what happens if you change the writeType to (WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE)? Also, can you share where onCharacteristicWrite() is called? Just to double check that the implementation is correct and that you are in fact seeing multiple writes to the same characteristic.

Comment: Writing with WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE produces the same result. The duplicate write (before processing) was proven by another team member working on the receiver.